# Multiple directory file operations

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, batch

In windows, I would like to use some sort of batch file to unzip files on multiple directory at once.

For example :

> Initial directory
>
> --Foo1
>
> ----file1.zip
>
> --Foo2
>
> ----Foo2.zip

The script would run with the Foo as the initial directory and search for the available sub directory and extract all the files on theses directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `FOR` command with the `/R` parameter:

```
FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

    Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
    statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
    specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
    assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
    will just enumerate the directory tree.
```

Type `help for` at the Command Prompt for full details on usage.

And remember, if using variables in a script you need to use `%%` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it :

```
@setlocal
@echo off
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%
for /F %%i in ('dir /s/b *.rar') do call :do_extract "%%i"
goto :eof

:do_extract
echo %1
mkdir %~1.extracted
pushd %~1.extracted
unrar e %1
popd
```

Comment: This will only work if WinRAR is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell (v3+):

```
cd "Foo1";dir *.zip -rec|%{eXpand-archive "$($_.fullname)" -des "$($_.parent)\"}
```