# Apply jpegtran.exe to directory

Tags: windows, batch, jpeg

I am trying to optimize a directory of images with jpegtran.exe but I can't figure out how to make it work. Does anyone have experience with this?

I found this article [about scripting jpegtran](http://blog.stationfour.com/automating-png-jpg-image-optimization-in-windows/)
 but its not recursive and I don't want to have to click hundreds of times.

Thanks!

Ended up finding a similar post to the answer: [Similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/189629/multiple-directory-file-operations?rq=1)

ANSWER: `FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /s/b *.*.jpg') DO ("jpegtran.exe" -optimize -progressive -copy none "%%i" "%%i")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify that batch for recursive operation by referring to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397674/windows-batch-file-looping-through-directories-to-process-files

You also have an option of creating optimized image dir inside each dir or one single dir containing all the optimized images..